# emacs programmatically change window size

Tags: emacs, lisp, window, size, buffer

I would like to implement automatic collapse of compilation buffer to small size (but not close at a delete windows), such that upon successful compilation to window is shrunk to minimum size.

`get-buffer-create` returns a buffer. how can I `shrink-window` on window associated with that buffer?  also, is there a way to store previous window size?

It is my first foray into emacs lisp programming, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe there are two ways to solve this problem.

The first is to use the hook `'compilation-finish-functions', which
is:

> [A list of f]unctions to call when a compilation process finishes.
>    Each function is called with two arguments: the compilation buffer,
>    and a string describing how the process finished.

Which leads to a solution like this:

```
(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'my-compilation-finish-function)
(defun my-compilation-finish-function (buffer resstring)
  "Shrink the window if the process finished successfully."
  (let ((compilation-window-height (if (string-match-p "finished" resstring) 5 nil)))
    (compilation-set-window-height (get-buffer-window buffer 0))))
```

The only problem I have with that solution is that it assumes that success can be determined by finding the string "finished" in the result string.

The other alternative is to advise `'compilation-handle-exit` - which
gets passed the exit-status explicitly.  I wrote this advice which
shrinks the window when the exit status is non-zero.

```
(defadvice compilation-handle-exit (around my-compilation-handle-exit-shrink-height activate)
  (let ((compilation-window-height (if (zerop (car (ad-get-args 1))) 5 nil)))
    (compilation-set-window-height (get-buffer-window (current-buffer) 0))
    ad-do-it))
```

Note: if the `*compilation*` window is still visible when you do your second compile, it will not be resized larger upon failure.  If you want it to be resized, you'll need to specify a height instead of `nil`.  Perhaps this would be to your liking (changing the first example):

```
(if (string-match-p "finished" resstring) 5 (/ (frame-height) 2))
```

The `nil` was replaced with `(/ (frame-height) 2)`